# Closure of the intersection of two convex sets

Tags: general-topology, geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $C$ and $C'$ be two convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with nonempty intersection. Is it true that 
$$
\overline{C\cap C'} = \overline{C}\cap \overline{C'} ?
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can take $H_1 = \{(x,y) \in R^2, y > 0 \}$ and $H_2 = \{(x,y) | y < 0 \}$. Then let $p = (0,0)$, and let $A = H_1 \cup p$ and $B = H_2 \cup p$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it still not true when one of the two sets $C$ or $C'$ is an open halfspace ?

Comment: @Phil-W I don't understand your question. In my example both sets where open half spaces. This isn't necessary, you can cook up other examples. It was just the easiest to write down. Start with a counter example to your claim when the intersection is not required to be nonempty, then you can add a point to make the intersection non-empty.

Comment: in your example, neither $A$ or $B$ are open halfspaces. I'm asking if we can still have a counter example when $A$ or $B$ is an open halfspace.

Comment: @Phil-W Oh I see, yes you are right. You can modify this example by taking one set to be the open upper half space, and the other set to be the convex hull of the lower half space union the interval [-1,1] in the y-axis.

Comment: I am not sure I see why this one is a counter-example, wouldn't the closure of intersection be the closed strip $0\leq y\leq 1$, which would then be also the intersection of the closure?

Comment: @Phil-W The problem is that there would be points along the x-axis far away from the origin that would be in the intersection of the closures, but not the closure of the intersection.

Comment: Since you take the convex hull, wouldn't any point on the x-axis actually be in the intersection ?

Comment: @Phil-W Yes, you're right. My mistake.

Comment: No problem, I will ask this new problem in another question.